# Groupby and append lists and strings

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to group-by the values in my "value_1" column. But my last column is made up of lists. When I try to group-by using my "value_1" column, the column made up of lists disappears.

Dataframe:

```
 value_1:        value_2:           value_3:               list: 
 american     california, nyc      walmart, kmart      [supermarket, connivence] 
 canadian         toronto            dunkinDonuts      [coffee]
 american          texas                               [state]
 canadian                             walmart          [supermarket] 
   ...              ...                 ...              ....
```

My expected output is:

```
value_1:        value_2:              value_3:             list: 
american   california, nyc, texas   walmart, kmart      [supermarket, connivence, state] 
canadian         toronto         dunkinDonuts, walmart  [coffee, supermarket]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create dynamically dictionary by all columns with no `list` and `value_1` and for `list` use lambda function with list comprehension with flatenning:

```
f1 = lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna())
#alternative for join only strings
#f1 = lambda x: ', '.join([y for y in x if isinstance(y, str)])
f2 = lambda x: [z for y in x for z in y]
d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['value_1','list']), f1)
d['list'] = f2 

df = df.groupby('value_1', as_index=False).agg(d)
print (df)
     value_1                 value_2                value_3  \
0   american  california, nyc, texas         walmart, kmart   
1   canadian                 toronto  dunkinDonuts, walmart   

                               list  
0  [supermarket, connivence, state]  
1             [coffee, supermarket]
```

**Explanation**:

`f1` and `f2` are lambda functions.

First remove missing values (if exist) and `join` strings with separator:

```
f1 = lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna())
```

First get only strings values (omit missing values, because `NaN`s) and `join` strings with separator:

```
f1 = lambda x: ', '.join([y for y in x if isinstance(y, str)])
```

First get all string values with filtering empty strings and `join` strings with separator:

```
f1 = lambda x: ', '.join([y for y in x if y != ''])
```

Function `f2` is for [flatten lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952), because after aggregation get nested lists like `[['a','b'], ['c']]`

```
f2 = lambda x: [z for y in x for z in y]
```

Answer (score 7):

You could [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) `value_1` and aggregate the columns containing strings with the following function:

```
def str_cat(x):
    return x.str.cat(sep=', ')
```

And use [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) to append the lists in the column `list`:

```
df.replace('',None).groupby('value_1').agg({'list':'sum', 'value_2': str_cat,
                                            'value_3': str_cat})

                        list                       value_2  \
value_1                                                              
american  [supermarket, connivence, state]  california, nyc, texas   
canadian             [coffee, sipermarket]          toronto, texas   

                    value_3  
value_1                                 
american  walmart, kmart, dunkinDonuts  
canadian         dunkinDonuts, walmart
```